# Is http_listener in cpprestsdk multithreaded?

Tags: c++

Do you know if http_listener in cpprestsdk multithreaded?

If yes, how to config the thread numbers? I want to let it have 1 thread.

Comment: It's multithreaded, they use a threadpool to launch the task

Comment: And they hard code the threadpool to 40, IIRC

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/3070ca21ed665a5aeb7d0cfe28f7f21d6c062a92/Release/src/pplx/threadpool.cpp#L57

It appears to be hard coded to 40.

But, if you change the number on that line, it looks like that should do it.

Comment: I'm using NuGet package. Maybe I should switch to lib crow which has config for threading.